# How to get attributes with namespace "android" in custom TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view, android-custom-attributes

In custom `TextView` I'm trying to obtain value of a `text` attribute (for example).

```
TypedArray values = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView);
String text = values.getString(com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView_text);
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> package com.android.internal.R does not exist

So how to retrieve "default" attributes of TextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal.R class isn't visible so you can only read them through their accessor methods and only once your super constructor has been called.

See the [TextView source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) to see how it works internally.

Comment: What do you mean by accessor methods?

Answer (score 7):

If you want have an access to those 'android' attributes you can 'override' them: in your declarable-styleable declare eg.

```
<attr name="android:padding"/>
```

Then you can easily obtain it this way:

```
int padding = a.getInt(R.styleable.CustomView_android_padding, -1);
```

Just for a record anwser is inspired by [source code](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) of TwoWayView layout implemented by Lucas Rocha. I think it is good example to analyse how to implement custom views

Comment: I couldn't find any other way to this approach. All other ways had some problems.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
val attrsArray = intArrayOf(android.R.attr.digits, android.R.attr.text)
val ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, attrsArray)
val digits = ta.getString(0)
val text = ta.getText(1)
ta.recycle()
```

Answer (score -1):

For accessing the resource of **com.android.internal.R**, you can use

```
Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage)
```

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030395/how-to-get-the-resource-id-from-value) may be helpful:

Comment: I always get `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0`