# How to get android default attributes in a custom view

Tags: android, android-widget, android-custom-view, custom-view, android-attributes

I have created a simple custom view that contains a `RelativeLayout` and an `EditText`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also I have added some custom attributes in `res/values/attrs.xml` and I retrieve these attributes in my custom view constructor and everything works ok.

Now, I want to retrieve `EditText` default attributes in my custom view for example I want to get `android:text` attribute in my custom view.

My custom view class (*simplified*):

```
public class CustomEditText extends RelativeLayout {
    private int panCount;

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.CustomEditText, 0, 0);
        try {
            this.panCount = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CustomEditText_panCount, 16);
        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that without redeclaring text attribute in `res/values/attrs.xml`?

Comment: it is confusing you are not using your view in xml code...! are you sure you have post the latest code. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8090772/7134908 it might solve your problem to set value in xml and get into Java vode

Comment: Could you add your `styleable` file for `CustomEditText`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attributes with namespace "android" in custom TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486791/how-to-get-attributes-with-namespace-android-in-custom-textview)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can add `android:text` to your declared syleable. But be sure to not redeclare it.

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomEditText">
    <attr name="android:text" />
</declare-styleable>
```

And then get this value from the style like you would with any other of your attributes with the index of `R.styleable.CustomEditText_android_text`.

```
CharSequence text = typedArray.getText(R.styleable.CustomEditText_android_text);
```

Comment: seems not to work with mixed-case like "android:textColor"?

Comment: This should not make a difference. I've never had issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can access attrs from custom view like this:

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val text = attrs?.getAttributeValue(
        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android",
        "text"
    )

    private val scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.values().getOrNull(
        attrs?.getAttributeIntValue(
            "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android",
            "scaleType",
            -1
        ) ?: -1
    )

    private val adjustViewBounds = attrs?.getAttributeBooleanValue(
        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android",
        "adjustViewBounds",
        false
    )

    private val verticalGapRes = attrs?.getAttributeResourceValue(
        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto",
        "flow_verticalGap",
        R.dimen.default_res
    )
}
```

In XML:

```
<com.example.testcustomview.CustomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:flow_verticalGap="@dimen/default_res"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do that.
Add an id to your edittext in xml and if you want to retrieve value of editText, simply use :

```
edittext.getText().toString()
```

Comment: I want to use android:text="some text" in xml and retrieve it in my custom view class like custom attributes

Comment: Please post your custom view class

Comment: I added my custom view class

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible because your customview extends **relativeLayout** and it doesnt have this attribute. You can access android:text or other attributes if you extend from **EditText** or TextView directly.

Answer (score -1):

You can build this using layout like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="My Custom View" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Your customview class will be like this

```
public class CustomEditText extends RelativeLayout {
    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        init();

    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        init();
    }

    // Here you can access your edittext text
    public void init() {
        View v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, this, true);
        EditText et = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        et.setText(" Custom RelativeLayout");
    }
}
```